# Angular-Formly can i render html within the form? (with scope vars)

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have a row based template and i need to display a calculation result ***within*** my form. the value is stored in the view model variable calc.

simple html element approach didnt work,

```
{
    key: 'html',
    template: '<div>' +
    'Hello the value  is {{vm.calc}}' +
    '</div>'
}
```

any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a type similar to

```
    formlyConfigProvider.setType({
        name: 'calculationResult',
        template: "<div>Hello the value  is {{to.calc}}</div>",
        wrapper: ['bootstrapLabel']
    });
```

then add this as a field to your form

```
{
    key: 'taskList',
    type: 'calculationResult',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Calculation Result',
      calc: ''
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.to.calc = $scope.model.c * $scope.model.b;
    }
}
```

I don't see any other better way to make the calculation display as a normal field value.